# How to fill half of a word with one colour and the other half with a different colour in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, gradient, fill

I want to recreate the text of a logo I have.

It had black half way down the text and then yellow for the other half.

How do I create text with a different colour on each half in Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can easily do this with a Gradient (without a gradient appearance). Don't let the term "Gradient" throw you. It's just the name of the tool, it doesn't *have* to mean a smooth transition between colors.

[image]

Just make certain the `Location` for both gradient stops is set the same.

You can even make this dynamic while keeping text **live**. So, it moves with the text, if the text is edited. See here: [Editable two side text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8195/editable-two-side-text/8196#8196)

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

1. Create two rectangles. Fill them with the desired colours
2. Place the text on top of the two rectangles. Make sure the text layer is the top-most of the three.
3. Select the three shapes (rectangles and text). Right click and select <kbd>Make Clipping Mask</kbd>

[image]

The text will function as the clipping mask. It will also still be editable! To edit the text or fine tune the position of the colours (rectangles), just double click on the group, like you do with any other clipping group.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways, here is one that would be much better if you wanted to change pieces of text on either side rather than half and half. For the most basic needs this is overkill.

1. Create text layer by clicking on [image: text tool ai icon]
   icon.
2. Go to `Object > Expand` in the top menu.

   [image]
3. Expand everything.

   [image]
4. Create a line across the middle of the text where you want the colours to meet with this tool [image]

   [image]
5. (optional) Create a new layer to make it easier to manage parts afterwards by clicking on the `Layer` panel and selecting the icon circled in red in the following screenshot.

   [image]
6. Select the `Live Paint Bucket`, found in the left tool menu like so or press <kbd>**K**</kbd> for the shortcut:

   [image]
7. When you hover over the text and line they should change colour and come up with the message 'Click to make a Live Paint Group` do so.

   [image]
8. Now when you hover over it should come up with outlines around shapes that are broken anywhere that a path intersects with another, like so:

   [image]

Colour in the segments you want to and enjoy! :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way, just for fun:

1. Create two rectangles. Fill them with the desired colours. Select both, drag them and drop them on the "Swatch" palette. A new swatch is created.
2. Type the text. With it selected, click on the swatch. The swatch is applied as the fill of the text.
3. Most likely the swatch will not be positioned correctly. Open the Move window (<kbd>Menu->Object->Transform->Move...</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+M</kbd>). Tick off "Transform Objects". Make sure "Transform Patterns" is ticked. This will allow you to move only the swatch but keep the text where it is. Tick also "Preview" so you see what is happening. Play with the vertical position (scroll button of the mouse works great) until the colours are right where you wanted them. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

Note: You can also play with the size of the swatch using the Scale window (<kbd>Menu->Object->Transform->Scale...</kbd>). Again, tick off "Transform Objects" and tick "Transform Patterns".

Comment: Nice trick! Very flexible. Random tip for anyone playing with this: be careful if you decide to try out ticking off `transform patterns`, as it will change all moving, even outside of the Move window, until you tick it back on. Definitely leave `Transform patterns` ticked!