# How to keep two colors in one vector shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need a circle (must be a vector) with two colors in it. If I divide the circle into two part equally and color them differently and Apply pathfinder -unite they become one and pick only one color. Ant way I can do that in Adobe illustrator?

[image]

Comment: Ok, so while you can do what you want with gradients you should think what ONE means. Why isnt group enough. Using illustrator is not about imposing your worldview on the software but turn your worldview into softwares worldview. From the computers perspective what you ask makes little sense.

Comment: yesssss yesss Gradient is the solution.

Comment: Just as long as you understand that this gradient may become fuzzy on print.

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8195/editable-two-side-text/8196#8196

Comment: @joojaa nah, not for print. I need it for web.

Comment: @Scott Thank you for sharing. I needed that.

Comment: Don't unite the shapes. Just select both shapes and group using Ctrl+G. There's no need for a gradient either. That's just adding unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @BillyKerr You are too intelligent. Why haven't I thought of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a gradient and set the location for both stops to 50%.

[image: gradient 50%]

Comment: :O :O Thank you so much!